# How to persist the Redux store data on refresh?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is there any way to store the redux store data on refresh ? i know we can use localstorage ,session storageea or redux-persist but which is better ? or any other way

Comment: its better to use redux-persist if you are using redux in your project

Comment: Cookies are another storage method. The best approach depends on your requirements. To clarify, you would have to persist the store constantly (after every action), since you can't know when the page is refreshed and you have no way to react to this in JS.